# cell fracture and reform following animated body

Tags: animation

I have a character animated, I created a duplicate of it using the Cell Fracture add on and want to duplicated body to split off the solid form, and then reform in the new position, following the deformation of the new character. any tips?

Comment: alternatively if someone knows how to key frame an entire cell fracture group with out individually selecting the visibility of all 100 pieces in the outliner, that would work too

Comment: You can mix a full transparent shader with your existent shader, and animate the factor of the mix.